# Domain Appended automatically to username with HTTPS

Tags: git, posh-git

I'm attempting to use git via posh-git and whenever the command prompts me for my username, when I attempt to input it it appends @mycompany.visualstudioonline.com to my username.

My username is "first.last@mycompany.com" so it then appends the doman prompts for the password for "first.last@mycompany.com@mycompany.visualstudioonline.com"

I've tried adding my username to the config file and it still appends the  @mycompany.visualstudioonline.com  on to my username automagically.  Is there any way to stop this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are being prompted for username and password because:

- you have not [set a default authentication username in your git config file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_avoiding_repetition);
- you are not using a credential manager.

To avoid having Git each time prompting for username&password you could:

- if you need to use HTTPS protocol, install the latest Git credential manager (for example for Windows [you would find it here on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases)), Git would then leverage this program to fetch the credentials: you would be prompted once, then each subsequent command you would issue the previously stored credentials will be provided automatically.
- use SSH protocol instead, and place your **public** SSH key (you should have created it beforehand inside your $HOME/.ssh) onto the allowed SSH keys of VSTS. Read the [VSTS documentation about how to create and upload your keys](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate).

**Note:**
Remember that for any given repository on VSTS you could access it by using either:

- HTTPS with a remote url like: `https://YOURACCOUNT.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/YOURTEAMPROJECT/_git/YOURREPONAME`
- SSH with a remote url like:
  `ssh://YOURACCOUNT@YOURACCOUNT.visualstudio.com:22/DefaultCollection/YOURTEAMPROJECT/_git/YOURREPONAME`

In a Git repository you can modify the url of the 'origin' remote (or any other remote indeed) at any time by the command:

```
>git remote set-url origin YOURURL
```

where (on VSTS) YOURURL is one of the two shown above.